# Чтение json файла

Tags: java, json, android-sdk, retrofit2

Есть json файл https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js, какие классы нужно создать для обработки его с помощью retrofit?

Сервис jsonschema2pojo.org выдает результат, при котором нужно создать десятки классов, под каждую валюту.

То есть как можно в 2 или 3 класса подготовить код для получения данных с файла?

Answer (score 0):

jsonschema2pojo.org, как и аналоги редко могут выдать приемлемый результат для чего-то сложного или не совсем стандартного. В вашем случае вам надо всего 2 класса - один для корневого объекта и один - для деталей валюты. А в первом пропишите примерно так: `Map<String, CurrencyDetails> Valute;`.

Опционально можно все валюты в enum записать, но это уже если хочется/надо/не лень и есть полный список возможных валют.